# Printing multiple plots using if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a report using r markdown that I can toggle between color and black and white. I've created a set of graphs using ggplot and saved them to objects, with a color and black and white version of each. To toggle the report I've created separate variables.

```
color <- 1
bw <- 0
```

In the code chunks for my report sections, I'm using if statements to check the values of the variables above and print the graphs.

```
if(color > 0) graph1_color
if(color > 0) graph2_color
if(bw > 0) graph1_bw
if(bw > 0) graph2_bw
```

When I knit my report, all of my intended graphs show up. If i set color and `bw <- 1`, all graphs. If just `color <- 1`, both color graphs, and if just `bw <- 1`, both bw graphs.

My issue is when I have 6 or seven graphs and I dont want to write `if(color > 0) graph1_color` for each of the graphs. Instead I used the following:

```
if(color > 0) {
graph1_color
graph2_color
}
if(bw > 0) {
graph1_bw
graph2_bw
}
```

But when I do this, only the last graph prints, eg graph2 prints but not graph1. What do I need to change in my `if` statement to get all of the graphs within the squiggle brackets to show?

Comment: I reproduced this using some random graphs.  It works for me. Are you knitting the notebook and it doesn't show both graphs...or is the RStudio plot window not showing both graphs?

Comment: Knitting the notebook to PDF and only the last object is shown. When I just run the code, the last object is shown in the viewer and if I hit the back arrow I get a "server Error: Invalid plot index" error

Comment: @MorganBrowning: what if you use `print(xxx)` instead?

Comment: @Tung, adding `print(xxx)` works, but I'm not sure I understand, and it also defeats the purpose a bit because I might as well just have `if(color > 0) in front of each object